# How to redirect to a specific url in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I did not understand how to create question title out of this problem.

Okay,

I am working on `.htaccess` and I tried to rewrite url

By this `RewriteRule ^fc.com/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?s=$1` and so far
`fc.com/abc123` works.

I tried to test it by `<a href="index.php?s=abc123">Test</a>`

It didn't work (as planned) but how do I redirect to `fc.com/abc123` if a request if been made for `index.php?s=abc123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /fc.com/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^fc.com/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```